# Continuity and metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$.

1. Show that $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous
2. Let $X'$ denote a space having the same underlying set as $X$. Show that if $d: X' \times X' \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous, then the topology of $X'$ is finer that the topology of $X$.

I know how to approach question 1 (I think I am doing it right):

Let $(x, y) \in X \times X$; We want to prove that given $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists opensets $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ such that $$d\left(U, V\right) \subset \left(d\left(x, y\right) - \epsilon, d\left(x, y\right) + \epsilon\right)$$
Let $U = B_d(x, \frac \epsilon 2)$ and $V = B_d(y, \frac\epsilon 2)$. From triangle inequality, we have: $\forall (x', y') \in U \times V$:
$$d(x,y) - \epsilon\leq d(x, y) - d(x, x') - d(y, y')\leq d(x', y') \leq d(x, x') + d(x, y) + d(y, y') \leq d(x, y) + \epsilon$$
Therefore we have $d\left(U, V\right) \subset \left(d\left(x, y\right) - \epsilon, d\left(x, y\right) + \epsilon\right)$, which means it's continuous.

However, I don't know how to approach the second question. Aren't this trivial given the fact that $X'$ has the same underlying set as $X$? Because then for any opensets in $X$, it is automatically in $X'$. Why $d$ still have to be continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for 2): Let $U$ be open in $(X,d)$ and $x \in U$. There exists $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subset U$. Now consider $E=\{(u,v): d(u,v) <r\}$ This is open in $X'\times X'$ with respect to  the product topology.  This implies that $B_d(x,r)=\{y: (x,y) \in E\}$ is open in $X'$. We have proved that each point $x$ of $U$ belongs to an open set in $X'$ which is contained in $U$. It follows that $U$ is a union of open sets in $X'$. Thus every open set in $(X,d)$ is open in $X'$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the question now. However, how do you get from $E$ is open in $X' \times X'$ to $B_d(x, r)$ is open in $X'$? I can't seem to get the implication here.

Comment: $B_d(x,r)$ is the inverse image of $E$ under the continuous map $y \to (x,y)$. [$x$ is fixed here]. @Prosthobotics

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you so much. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach the first part.

To prove continuity, you can apply the sequential characterization of it.

Precisely, let $(x_{n},y_{n})$ be a sequence in $X\times X$ which converges to $(x,y)\in X\times X$.

Then the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,y) \leq d_{X}(x,y_{n}) + d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n}) + d_{X}(x_{n},y)
\end{align*}

as well as the next relation:
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n}) \leq d_{X}(x_{n},y) + d_{X}(x,y) + d_{X}(x,y_{n})
\end{align*}

Consequently, due to limit properties and convergence of the sequences $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle d_{X}(x,y) = \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x,y) \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n})\\\\
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n})\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x,y) = d_{X}(x,y)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Finally, due to the squeeze theorem, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(x_{n},y_{n}) = d_{X}(x,y)
\end{align*}

whence the continuity follows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is definitely a nice way to approach. Do you have hint for the second one?

Comment: What do you mean by "having the same underlying set as $X$"?

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. I am not sure what it means and this is how it writes on the book. I thought it means: for any opensets in $X$, is in $X'$; But then aren't $X'$ finer by $X$ by definition? This is mainly why I asked this question.

Comment: I will think about it. If you think my answer deserves, give it an upvote.